# CPU Operational Load on WSL slows down entire computer

Tags: linux, windows, cpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server

I'm running a Dell XPS15 with 64 GB Ram and a i7-12700H (6 performance cores, 8 efficency cores). I just recently (read: 2 weeks ago) did a clean upgrade and reinstall to Windows 11 with all up-to-date drivers. This problem also existed on Windows 10.

I run Ubuntu WSL, and IntelliJ IDEA through GWSL XServer(?).

Whenever some load is running in my WSL instance, may that be the IDE indexing, a server running or recompiling, I can noticably see my windows slow down. That is, frames are dropping, programs are sluggish, and just a general bad experience. I even have Youtube videos suddenly stop playing and break as if the video card driver failed. During those instances the task manager only displays a load of about 5-10% CPU usage on the WSL process. WSL RAM is steadily in the 16GB to 32GB area, but not anywhere close to maxing out the 64GB available.

My immediate suspicioun might be that CPU scheduling / context switching / something else CPU related might be at fault here, but I'm not entirely sure if that is true.

```
[wsl2]
systemDistro="C:\\System\\system.vhd"

[system-distro-env]
WSLG_USE_MSTSC=true
WESTON_RDP_WINDOW_SNAP_ARRANGE=true
WESTON_RDPRAIL_SHELL_LOCAL_MOVE=true
```

Comment: Can you share with us your .wslconfig file?

Comment: Went ahead and added the .wslconfig. 
For reference, I played around with adding `processors=6` (or any other number) to the `[wsl2]` before, but I couldn't notice any feasible change.

Comment: Try 2 processors and 8 gig ram first. (Check it on the wsl console.)